# Decomposing direct product of spin-$s$ representation into direct sum

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

Direct product of spin-$s$ representations can be decomposed into direct sum of some other spin-s representation:
$$
\{j\}\otimes\{s\}=\sum_{\oplus l=|j-s|}^{j+s}\{l\}
$$
Howard Georgi gives a hint in his book *Lie Algebras in Particle Physics* that this can be proved using the highest weight decomposition. I'm not sure how to do this in a general form. By the way, I used to read about another way to prove this, namely by making representation with tensors (symmetrizing, antisymmetrizing and traceless conditions, like that). I wonder what's the connection between these 2 methods?

Comment: *I'm not sure how to do this in a general form.* Is this because Georgi doesn’t explain highest weight decomposition or because you don’t understand his explanation?

Comment: Do you understand the root system of SU(2)? Do you understand the weight diagram of an SU(2) irrep {j}? Do you understand how to combine weight diagrams when forming a tensor product of irreps?

Comment: *I'm not sure how to do this in a general form.* Do you mean that you can decompose specific cases like $\{2\}\otimes\{3/2\}$ but not the general case $\{j\}\otimes\{s\}$?

Comment: Uhm I think I'd better go on reading, it seems that Georgi has discussed this later in his book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the highest-weight idea:

Consider a $2j+1$ representation of $su(2)$ with states $|j,m\rangle_1$, along with another $2s+1$ representation $|s,m'\rangle_2$, consider
$$|j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 = |j,j\rangle_1 |s,s\rangle_2.$$
The operator $T^3 = T^3_1 + T^3_2$ obviously satisfies
$$T^3 |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 = (j+s)|j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2.$$
Using
$$T^+ |j,m\rangle = d_m^+ |j,m+1\rangle = \sqrt{(j-m)(j+m+1)}|j,m+1\rangle$$
we see that the raising operator $T^+ = T^+_1 + T^+_2$ satisfies
$$T^+ |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 = 0,$$
so that $|j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2$ is the highest weight state of a $2(j+s)+1$ representation, and so can be denoted
$$|j+s,j+s\rangle = |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2.$$

Now apply the lowering operator $T^- = T^-_1 + T^-_2$ to this state. Using
$$T^- |j,m\rangle = d_m^- |j,m-1\rangle = \sqrt{(j+m)(j-m+1)}|j,m-1\rangle$$
we see
\begin{align}
T^- |j+s,j+s\rangle &= \sqrt{((j+s)+(j+s))((j+s)-(j+s)+1)}|j+s,j+s-1\rangle \\
&= \sqrt{2(j+s)}|j+s,j+s-1\rangle
\end{align}
however, in direct product notation, this reads as
\begin{align}
T^- |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 &= \sqrt{(j+j)(j-j+1)}|j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 + \sqrt{(s+s)(s-s+1)} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2 \\
&= \sqrt{2j} |j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 + \sqrt{2s} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2.
\end{align}
so that
$$|j+s,j+s-1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(j+s)}} (\sqrt{2j} |j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 + \sqrt{2s} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2).$$
This obviously lives in the $(j+s)$ representation,

By observation, the state
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(j+s)}} (\sqrt{2s} |j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 - \sqrt{2j} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2)$$
is orthogonal to this state, it has $T^3$ eigenvalue
$$(j+s-1),$$
and under $T^+$ it gets annihilated since
\begin{align}
(T^+_1 + T^+_2) \sqrt{2s} |j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 &= \sqrt{2s} \sqrt{(j-(j-1))(j+(j-1)+1)} |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 = \sqrt{2j} \sqrt{2s} |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 \\
(T^+_1 + T^+_2) \sqrt{2j} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2 &=  \sqrt{2j} \sqrt{(s-(s-1))(s+(s-1)+1)} |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2  =  \sqrt{2j} \sqrt{2s} |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2
\end{align}

Thus this state is the highest weight state of a $2(j+s-1) + 1$ representation, which we denote
$$|j+s-1,j+s-1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(j+s)}} (\sqrt{2s} |j-1\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2 - \sqrt{2j} |j\rangle_1 |s-1\rangle_2).$$
So far we have shown that $|j+s,j+s\rangle$ and $|j+s,j+s-1\rangle$ and $|j+s-1,j+s-1\rangle$ are orthogonal basis vectors in the representation, where the first two live in a $(j+s)$ rep, while the last lives in a $(j+s-1)$ rep.

We can obviously now repeat the same procedure over and over again until we reach the lowest weight states of the two original reps, e.g. in this case applying the lowering operator to our two states, and then finding a third state orthogonal to these, living in a $2(j+s-2)+1$ representation, etc...

Note any state like $|j+s,j+s\rangle$ or $|j+s,j+s-1\rangle$ above reduced to a linear combination of $|j,m\rangle_1 |s,m'\rangle_s$ terms. In general, we can insert a 'resolution of the identity' and re-write something like $|j+s,j+s\rangle$ as
\begin{align}
|j+s,j+s\rangle &= \sum_{m,m'} |j,m\rangle_1 |s,m'\rangle_2  ({_1} \langle j,m|  {_2} \langle s,m'|j+s,j+s\rangle) \\
&= |j,j\rangle_1 |s,s\rangle_2 \\
&= |j\rangle_1 |s\rangle_2
\end{align}
where the coefficients $_1\langle j,m| _2 \langle s,m'|j+s,j+s\rangle$ are called Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

The basic link to tensor methods is discussed in Georgi, ch. 10, where he points out that a spin$-j$ representation $|j,m\rangle$ [can be represented by](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Evbouchar/MAPH464/section-representation-sun-tensors.html) a rank-2j symmetric tensor, and computes Clebsch-Gordan coefficients using tensors.

Comment: Maybe I missed something but why does the process end at |j-s| ?